# Is there a Budgie applet list?

Tags: applet, budgie

I recently installed Budgie just for the hell of it. I really like gnome but it had some weird stuff going on.

Budgie is very similar and seems to have the same thing going on as gnome with extensions, but with applets. However it seems that I can only find them by knowing the names or what they do. Is there a centralized of them? Seems like a pain in the ass so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, there is.

It's in Budgie Welcome.

Here's the GIF if you can't navigate it:

[image: GIF]